# Is writev() really atomic?

Tags: c++, c, linux-kernel, system-calls

Here is what `man writev` says:

> The data transfers performed by readv() and writev() are atomic: the data written by writev() is written as a single block that is not intermingled with output from writes in other processes (but see pipe(7) for an exception); analogously, readv() is guaranteed

This is from `man 7 pipe`:

> ```
>    O_NONBLOCK disabled, n <= PIPE_BUF
>           All n bytes are written atomically; write(2) may block if there is not room for n bytes to be written immediately
>
>    O_NONBLOCK enabled, n <= PIPE_BUF
>           If there is room to write n bytes to the pipe, then write(2) succeeds immediately, writing all n bytes; otherwise write(2) fails, with errno set to EAGAIN.
>
>    O_NONBLOCK disabled, n > PIPE_BUF
>           The write is nonatomic: the data given to write(2) may be interleaved with write(2)s by other process; the write(2) blocks until n bytes have been written.
>
>    O_NONBLOCK enabled, n > PIPE_BUF
>           If  the pipe is full, then write(2) fails, with errno set to EAGAIN.  Otherwise, from 1 to n bytes may be written (i.e., a "partial write" may occur; the caller should check the return value from write(2) to see how many bytes were actually written), and these bytes may be interleaved with writes by other processes.
> ```

```
$ cat writev.c
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/uio.h>

int
main(int argc,char **argv) {
    static char part1[] = "ST";
    static char part2[] = "\n";
    struct iovec iov[2];

    iov[0].iov_base = part1;
    iov[0].iov_len = strlen(part1);

    iov[1].iov_base = part2;
    iov[1].iov_len = strlen(part2);

    writev(1,iov,2);

    return 0;
}
```

```
$ gcc writev.c
```

```
$ unbuffer bash -c 'for ((i=0; i<50; i++)); do ./a.out & ./a.out; done' | wc -c
300  # < PIPE_BUF

# Run the following several times to get the output corrupted
$ unbuffer bash -c 'for ((i=0; i<50; i++)); do ./a.out & ./a.out; done' | sort | uniq -c
      4 
     92 ST
      4 STST
```

If writev is atomic (according to documentation) can anybody explain why the outputs of different writes are interleaved?

**Update:**

Some relevant data from `strace -fo /tmp/log unbuffer bash -c 'for ((i=0; i<10000; i++)); do ./a.out & ./a.out; done' | sort | uniq -c`

```
13301 writev(1, [{iov_base="ST", iov_len=2}, {iov_base="\n", iov_len=1}], 2 <unfinished ...>
13302 mprotect(0x56397d7d8000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
13302 mprotect(0x7f7190c68000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
13302 munmap(0x7f7190c51000, 90695)     = 0
13302 writev(1, [{iov_base="ST", iov_len=2}, {iov_base="\n", iov_len=1}], 2) = 3
13301 <... writev resumed> )            = 3
24814 <... select resumed> )            = 1 (in [4])
13302 exit_group(0 <unfinished ...>
13301 exit_group(0 <unfinished ...>
13302 <... exit_group resumed>)         = ?
13301 <... exit_group resumed>)         = ?
24814 futex(0x55b5b8c11cc4, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647 <unfinished ...>
24807 <... futex resumed> )             = 0
24814 <... futex resumed> )             = 1
24807 futex(0x7f7f55e8f920, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL <unfinished ...>
13302 +++ exited with 0 +++
24807 <... futex resumed> )             = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
13301 +++ exited with 0 +++
24807 futex(0x7f7f55e8f920, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1 <unfinished ...>
24814 futex(0x7f7f55e8f920, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1 <unfinished ...>
24807 <... futex resumed> )             = 0
24814 <... futex resumed> )             = 0
24807 read(4,  <unfinished ...>
24814 select(6, [5], [], [], NULL <unfinished ...>
24807 <... read resumed> "STST\n\n", 4096) = 6
24808 <... wait4 resumed> [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 13302
24807 write(1, "STST\n\n", 6 <unfinished ...>
```

Comment: There's no need to use `unbuffer` if you're not using `stdio`.

Comment: I tried it without `unbuffer`: `for ((i=0; i<50; i++)); do ./a.out & ./a.out; done | sort | uniq -c` and got `100 ST` on Debian 3.2.89-2.

Comment: It is definitely being caused by something that `unbuffer` is doing.

Comment: You ask it to write 2 buffers in the command. I think, writing of a single buffer is atomic. But different buffers can interleave. Your output supports this theory. it is also hinted int he man documentation.

Comment: You are writing to a pipe. `writev()` to a pipe is explicitly stated to be an exception to the rule. Unclear what you're really asking here.

Comment: The POSIX specification for [`writev()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/writev.html) appears to guarantee atomicity for each item within the vector, but not for all elements of the vector at once.  The man page you quote seems to go beyond what POSIX demands — but superficially, it appears that the implementation doesn't match the claims of the man page.  I wonder if the atomicity works with threads in a process rather than across processes?  (This is speculation; I've not played with threads — or the process version.)

Comment: Did all the `writev` calls return 3? Looking at your strace output, it appears not. Some of them returned 2.

Comment: Actually, I cannot tell from the strace output if any of the `writev` calls returned 2.

Comment: @user207421: The program is not really writing to a pipe.  With `unbuffer`, the program `a.out` has its fd 1 going to a pseudo-tty, and there is an auxiliary process that collects the data written to the pty and writes it out to the pipe.  The idea is that this will encourage a program using stdio to line-buffer.  So it appears that terminals are another (undocumented) exception to this rule.

Answer (score 2):

As specified, yes for pipes, when the total `iov` length does not exceed `PIPE_BUF`, because:

> The writev() function shall be equivalent to write(), except as described below

with no exceptions made for pipes (the word pipe does not even appear in [the `writev` specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/writev.html)).

In practice for Linux, maybe not. `writev` equivalence to a single `write` only works on kernel file types that implement the "new" (as of 15 years ago or so) `iov`-based read/write backends. Some, like terminals, only implement the old interfaces that use a single buffer, and Linux emulates the `writev` (or `readv`) as multiple `write` calls (or resp. `read` calls). The `readv` case is also problematic, as you can see [in this commit to musl libc](https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/commit?id=2cff36a84f268c09f4c9dc5a1340652c8e298dc0).

I'm not sure whether pipes are affected by this issue or not. You'd have to dig into the kernel sources.

Comment: Terminals are exactly the point here, because that's what `unbuffer` does; it causes the program's standard output fd to go to a pseudo-terminal (which is then written to the "original" standard output by an auxiliary process).  But `a.out` here is not actually writing to a pipe, so the bit about pipes is not relevant.

Comment: @NateEldredge: What is `unbuffer`? A program to wrap execution with stdout going through a pty to trick the program into using line buffering? If so, then yes, the Linux tty bug I cited would explain exactly what OP is seeing.

Comment: Yes, that's what it is.  It's part of [Expect](https://core.tcl.tk/expect/index).

Comment: @NateEldredge, you are right, the output is not pipe but pty. Cannot mark the comment as the answer.